# How to connect QT with VLC player

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc

In my QT GUI application I need playback some video files. I tried the MediaPlayer component (qtmultimedia 5.0), but it cannot read the video containers (mp4/mkv) that I'm using, which VLC player runs without any problem. So I found an library called **vlc-qt** (http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt) and downloaded the windows binaries (which seem to be compiled using MSVC 11.0), but it fails to link on QT Creator MinGW (it shows 16 lines of undefined reference), maybe because **vlc-qt** is compiled with a different compiler than the one used to build the QT app.

I can't find any working references or documentation on this topic, so does anybody know how can I make this?

---

More details:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- QT Creator 3.0.1 | QT 5.2.1
- vlc-qt 0.9.0
- C++

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is compiled using MSVC so it can not be liked to your application with a MinGW compiler. You can get the code from [Here](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt) and compile it with MinGW compiler. After that you can link it to your app.

You can download and install CMake from [Here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html). Next open the file named "CMakeLists.txt" from the root of the VLC_Qt source code with Qt Creator. Click "Next" and then after selecting the desired Generator click "Run CMake". WHen everything completes click finish. Now you can build the entire VLC-Qt with Qt Creator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you show an example of how to build a library like this with MinGW?

Comment: If you install CMake you can compile it by selecting the Generator related to MinGW.

Comment: I tried to build with cmake on qt, but when I click "Run CMake" it shows the following error: `CMake Error at cmake/FindLIBVLC.cmake:90 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find LibVLC
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:142 (FIND_PACKAGE)`

Comment: This error means that you're trying to open a project which depends on LibVLC (previously compiled and installed system-wide). You should install libVLC SDK. It is easy on Linux but a little tricky on Windows.

Comment: Ok, I will try to install libvlc sdk then. Thank you for the help!